# Filtering a value from Data Table in C# for 100k rows interatively is taking around 15 minutes

Tags: c#, select, filter, datatable, sql-like

In below code I've used it 2 methods of doing this (1 being commented).

```
protected DataRow[] GetRows(DataTable dataTable, string keyColumn, object KeyValue)
{
    DataRow[] rows = null;

    /*dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[" + keyColumn + "] Like '%" + keyValue.ToString() + "%'";
    dataTable = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
    rows = dataTable.Select();*/

    rows = dataTable.Select("[" + keyColumn + "] Like '%" + keyValue.ToString() + "%'");

    return rows;
}
```

Is there any faster way to do the same task? This method GetRows is being called for about a thousand number of times; dataTable has 100 000 rows.

The actual BusinessLogic looks like

```
        public void BusinessLogic()
        {

            foreach (DataRow dRow in dataTableOne.Rows)
            {

                var primaryKey = dRow["PrimaryColumn"];

                DataRow[] rows;
                    rows = GetRows(dataTableTwo,"PrimaryColumn" , primaryKey);

        /*
            Business Logic
        */

        }
        }
```

Comment: FYI... 1 lakh/lac = 100,000

Comment: This method GetRows is being called for about a thousand number of times; dataTable is having around lakh number of rows.

Comment: Do you really need the `LIKE` with wildcards on a "key column"?

Comment: yes Tim, I need to have a Like with wildcards, is there any alternative of Like which can be substituted for in this logic?

Comment: @VarunChaturvedi: Not really. You need to show more of your code, maybe then we could improve it with a diffewrent approach. Why do you need so many `GetRows`?

Comment: actually there are two Data Tables, lets say the other being mainDataTable. The business logic wants me to iterate through all the rows in the mainDataTable (having around thousand or so rows) and get corresponding rows (based on primary key on mainDataTable) from dataTable(in the example above, having around a lakh rows) and then apply the business logic on the rows returned by the above method. If I try `rows = dataTable.Select(@"[" + keyColumn + "]='" + keyValue + "'");` it takes only 2-3 minutes. But using this `LIKE` wildcard the time goes up to ~15 minutes.

Comment: You can use `Linq-To-DataSet` and `Enumerable.Join` to link both tables which would be much more efficient. But to show you an example we need to see more of the _business logic_ (the loop).

Comment: added the business logic structre, Tim

Comment: Does your table have an index on the key column?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Linq` for me it's up to 10 times faster:

```
protected static DataRow[] GetRows(DataTable dataTable, string keyColumn, string keyValue)
{
    return dataTable.Rows
        .OfType<DataRow>()
        .Where(row => SafeContains(row[keyColumn], keyValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .ToArray();
}

private static bool SafeContains(object source, string value, StringComparison stringComparison)
{
    var s = source as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return false;
    return s.IndexOf(value, stringComparison) >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this and I'm not sure of the memory implications, but if it is the `like` command that is causing the slowness, then what if you avoid it by looping through the first DataTable and storing the primaryKeys for each of your 1000 records and also create a separate DataTable

```
var primaryKeys = new string[dataTableOne.Rows.Count];
var dataTables = new DataTable[dataTableOne.Rows.Count] ;

for (int i= 0 ; i < dataTableOne.Rows.Count ; i++)
{
    dataTables[i] = new DataTable();
    primaryKeys[i] = (string) dataTableOne.Rows[i]["PrimaryColumn"];
}
```

Then loop through the rows in dataTableTwo and check if the primary key from table2 matches any of primary keys and if it does, then add to the appropriate datatable

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTableTwo.Rows)
{
    var key2 = (string) dr["PrimaryColumn"] ;

    for (int j= 0 ; j < dataTableOne.Rows.Count ; j++)
    {
        if (key2.Contains(primaryKeys[j]))
            dataTables[j].Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Finally you should end up with your 1000 datatables

```
for (int j= 0 ; j < dataTableOne.Rows.Count ; j++)
{
    // Process Business logic on dataTables[j] 
}
```